# is it safe in golang 1.17 to change the pointer receiver's value with atomic swap pointer

Tags: go, atomic, swap, receiver

golang 1.17 changed from stack to register to handle the params

is it safe when i use atomic.SwapPointer to change the pointer receiver's value

below is the code

```
//like this
func (this *A) Replace(a *A) {
    //other business logic
    //....
    //business logic end
    atomic.SwapPointer((*unsafe.Pointer)(unsafe.Pointer(&this)), unsafe.Pointer(a))
}
```

Comment: Unsafe is not safe. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: On a side note, it is recommended *not* to name your method receivers things like `this` or `self`.

Comment: It's not only unsafe, it's also useless. It accomplishes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> [I]s it safe in golang 1.17 to change the pointer receiver's value with atomic swap pointer [?]

No. Use of package unsafe is unsafe by definition of unsafe.

("safe" in which sense?)

Comment: Unsafe it is for any definition of safe.

Comment: Is this really an answer? this could simply be a comment

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is doing what you want it to.  From the point-of-view of Go code, even "sensible" unsafe code, you cannot tell the difference between the register and stack ABI.  If you take the address of a parameter, if it was not already in memory, it will be stored to memory, and that will be its address.  If that address is passed to a function that "escapes" the address by storing it in a global or in the heap, then the memory for the parameter will actually be obtained by heap-allocating a slot for it and storing it there.  If this happens, then subsequent reference to the parameter will indirect through the hidden pointer to its heap address.